# Save PDF-File into BLOB-Column Oracle DB with INSERT statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, blob

I have to save a PDF-File into a BLOB-Column from a Oracle DB. 
I can't use Java and have to use an INSERT-Statement.

The only solutions I've found while searching were very complex.

Is there an easy solution like: `INSERT INTO (BLOB_COLUMN) VALUES(BLOBPDF("myPDF.pdf")` or something like that?

Comment: There are no such shortcuts when it comes to BLOBs. Try to understand those complex solutions, try to implement them and if at all you face any problems, post a question here.

Comment: That would be something your SQL client tool needs to support - unless you can copy the file to the database server. Then you could do that using PL/SQL

Comment: Convert the bytes to hexadecimal digits, then pass them to HEXTORAW inside INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use a stored procedure in Oracle where you pass the path to your PDF file and calling the stored procedure does the insert.

Look at the last two sample example [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2400953?tstart=0).

Comment: Thx for you answer. I think you have forgotten the links to the examples.

Comment: Added, you might want to know how stored procedures are created in Oracle and use them.Ideally, I would have used s3 to store files rather than storing them in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If the load is "one-shot" you can use SQLDeveloper.
Otherwise you can use sqlloader (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_params.htm) that is designed for this type of operations